# What was Wittgenstein's argument against Cantor's transfinite numbers and where did he make his objection?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, wittgenstein, anscombe

G. E. M. Anscombe had this to say about propositions in Wittgenstein's *Tractatus*: (page 137)

> It seems likely enough, indeed, that Wittgenstein objected to Cantor's result even at this date, and would not have accepted a Cantorian device for specifying an infinite subset of the elementary propositions such that a truth-function of it could not be generated by his formula. For though he came to think his idea wrong, it was certainly not through any conversion to Cantor that this happened. On the contrary: whether or no he already objected to Cantor at the time when he wrote the *Tractatus*, he certainly did so later.

What was Wittgenstein's argument against Cantor's transfinite numbers and where did he make his objection?

---

Anscombe, G. E. M. An Introduction to Wittgenstein's Tractatus. 1971. Reprinted by St. Augustine's Press.

Comment: As Anscombe says, he did not spell out an objection to the diagonal argument at the time of the Tractatus. At later dates, there are multiple passages in multiple works, many are cited by [SEP Wittgenstein’s Later Critique of Set Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/wittgenstein-mathematics/#WittLateCritSetTheoNonEnumVsNonDenu). He basically saw all reasoning about the transfinite as misleading abuse of familiar words, a "hocus pocus" of misdirection.

Comment: There's this quote on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversy_over_Cantor%27s_theory#Reception_of_the_argument) though I'm not clear where it comes from... (What's RFM?)

Comment: @Rusi Probably Wittgenstein's Remarks on the Foundations of Mathematics

Comment: Ludwig Wittgenstein, [Remarks on the Foundations of Mathematics (Bemerkungen uber die Grundlagen der Mathematik, Blackwell, 2nd ed 1978)](https://books.google.it/books?id=v3bZSQAACAAJ) Part I, Appendix II. The name "Cantor" does not appera in the *Tractatus* (and this is consistent with Anscombe assertion: "whether or no he already objected to Cantor at the time when he wrote the *Tractatus*, he certainly did so later.").